# How to use inplace in python after calling the function?

Tags: python, pandas

**Case : 1**

I have 7 columns which contain `"???"`. I have replaced the `"???"` with NAN using `np.nan`. When I tried to read the data frame again the same  `"???"` showing. How to use inplace and make it change in the main data frame?

**Case : 2**

I am using function to clean all the 7 columns and getting below error message

coding for **case : 1**

`df` is my data frame

```
df.iloc[:, 0:8].replace('???', np.nan)
```

I am getting NAN after running the above code.

Then I tried to read the df again then the same `"???"` is coming in the column.

Unable to paste the screenshot.

**Case: 2**

```
def cleaning(x):
    x = x.replace("???", np.nan)
    return(x)

df = df.iloc[:, 0:8]
df.applymap(cleaning)
```

all the columns dtype is object

**Error**:

```
TypeError: ('replace() argument 2 must be str, not float', 'occurred at index Transport')
```

Comment: for case1 `df.iloc[:, 0:8]=df.iloc[:, 0:8].replace('???', np.nan)` should work. You are unning the code but not assigning it back

Comment: You'll need to assign the values manipulated i.e replaced back to the df @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you need to assign it back to df[:, 0:8]:

**Case1**:

```
df.iloc[:, 0:8] =df.iloc[:, 0:8].astype(str).replace('???', np.nan)
```

**Case2**:

```
def cleaning(x):
    x =x.replace('???', np.nan)
    return(x)

df.iloc[:, 0:8] =df.iloc[:, 0:8].astype(str).apply(cleaning)
```

Comment: Hi Loochie, Thanks for your solutions. it works now. Just to clarify in case 1. Why did you choose df.iloc[:, 0:2] instead of 0:8. Either way, it works. Just want to know the reason. Unable to figure the solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the inplace flag and set it to true

```
df.iloc[:, 0:8].replace('???', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.NaN` is a **float**. and you are using the `str.replace()` function which needs **2 string parameters** as **old** and **replacement** value, you must use empty string instead of NaN.

Comment: Hi Mark, I changed into an empty string and its coming blank instead of ???. However, I checked the df again then the ??? appears. Do we need to use inplace? if so, how to use it?